# How to store twitter followers details into database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I want to create a script which will work like this.

**When someone follows my account, his/her details should get stored into mysql database**

I want to create this using php script.

Please suggest me how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could assign an event to your twitter button and make a form to be submitted to PHP code via ajax.

After the fill out your form, assign a function to your twitterbutton onclick:

```
$('#twitterButton').click(function() {
    $.post('yourphpfile.php', ('#yourform').serialize(), function (data) {
        alert('Thank you for following!');
    });
});
```

This is just a suggestion, though. Hope it helps!